# How to define start and end in query to a json-server?

Tags: database, json-server

when I do query like this:

```
http://localhost:3010/articles?_start=0&end=4
```

I get the whole data! whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!
the dear underline before the end parameter was missed! 
so should be like this:

```
http://localhost:3010/articles?_start=0&_end=4
```